# How to Create An AlertDialog that I can use throughout an Activity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How do I build an AlertDialog once and for all. I'll show it as at when needed all through the activity.

Comment: Consider using a Toast instead unless you want to force the user to acknowledge the alert message.

Comment: Yes, the user need to take actions with the negative and positive buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a method in any Util class as -

```
public static void showDialog(Context context, int msgResId) {
        if (context == null) return;
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setMessage(msgResId)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
```

And call from the activity anytime you want by calling -

```
showDialog(MainActivity.this, R.string.your_string_res_id);
```

For alert dialog with action buttons -

Declare the dialog outside any method -

```
private AlertDialog dialog;
```

You can create the dialog in Activity's `onCreate()` like this -

```
dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setMessage("Your message")
                .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                       //Your code
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                       //Your code
                })
                .create();
```

and whenever you want to show it you can show like this -

```
 dialog.show();
```

Comment: I'll configure everything about the dialog in the util class and this includes the negative and positive buttons. How do I show it in MainActivity.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I use this class

https://github.com/mauricioj/gals/blob/master/GalsM/src/br/ufscar/sigam/util/ModalDialog.java

You use new ModalDialog (this, "Example")

I hope this helps :)

in doModal () method should check this end

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
   msg.recycle ();
}
```